# Can I calculate the area of a closed surface on a sphere by its boundary using Stokes' Theorem?

Tags: area, surfaces, spheres, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

So I (just learned that I) can get the area of any closed area $S$ with boundary $\partial S$ on the flat plane through Stokes' (or in the simplified case Green's) theorem by using a vector field with constant curl:
$$
\iint_{S} (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}) \cdot d\vec{A} = \int_{\partial S} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}
$$
in 2D with the vector field
$$
\vec{F} = \begin{bmatrix} -y \\ x \end{bmatrix} ; \ \ \ \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} = 2
$$
gives me
$$
A = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial S} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial S} x\ dy - y\ dx
$$
Now my question:
Can I use the same approach to cactulate areas of regions on non-planar surfaces (e.g. a sphere) by using a vector field that is constant along their surfaces? (is that in principle a valid approach?)

And for that matter: is it even possible to define a vector field with constant curl relative to a sphere or even an arbitrary surface? Or do things like maybe the hairy ball theorem make this impossible?

A problem I could think of is that also by Stokes' theorem the integral of all the curl on a closed surface like a sphere must be zero, so can the curl of a vector field not be constant everywhere on a closed surface? Maybe you could still get a field with a singularity? Or maybe it is not constant everywhere but you can still extract the area? (Sry I'm bad at maths)

Many thanks!

Comment: You are asking great questions! These are the questions that lead to deep results about the *global* properties of vector fields on manifolds such as [the Poincaré–Hopf index theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) and provide links between analysis of integration of differential forms and the topology of the underlying manifold.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Just to note, the criterion we need to make this idea work is a vector field whose curl _has constant unit normal component along our surface_. On the unit sphere, for example, it's enough to arrange that$$\nabla\times F=\frac{(x, y, z)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$inside the spherical region whose area we want to calculate. (We cannot arrange that this equation holds everywhere on the sphere, but we _can_ cause it to hold everywhere on the sphere except one point.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, thanks, that's what I meant, I was arguably a bit imprecise with "constant along their surfaces" and "constant curl relative to a sphere" (meaning it should be dotted with the surface normal, which [I think] leads to the same constraint). Could you tell me where I can find the information on how to construct such a field?

Comment: Have you heard of or worked with "differential forms" and "exterior calculus"? If not, those should be good search terms; differential forms (rather than vector fields) are arguably the preferred formalism.